# Batch - set variable error; variable(%)(string)(%%a)(%)?

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, set

On the batch script I'm currently working on, I've encountered a bit of a problem.
What I want to happen is to set a variable as itself, but after it to be followed by a percentage mark, a letter, a number from a `for /l (#,#,#)` loop, then another percentage sign.
My code is currently as follows;

```
set value1=1
set value2=10
for /l %%a in (%value1%,1,%value2%) do (
set variable1=%variable1%%b%%a%
)
```

This doesn't give me a value for %variable1% at all, even after looping this 10 times. I've tried adding 'variable1= ' (without apostrophes) to the top, however that gave me the same result. After searching around, I figured that I should try and cancel out the %'s which are before the 'b' and after the 'a' - using %'s in front of them -,and my code ended up like this;

```
set value1=1
set value2=10
set variable1= 
for /l %%a in (%value1%,1,%value2%) do (
set variable1=%variable1%%b%%a%
)
```

This is the closest I got, however %variable1% would change the value to '%b1%', then '%b2%', then '%b3%', etc. Instead of tiling them up next to each other.

My desired result would be for, by the end of the loop, %variable1% to have a value of;           `%b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%%b5%%b6%%b7%%b8%%b9%%b10%`

Where is my code going wrong? It seems that it should give me my desired output, however quite clearly, it's not.

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set value1=1
set value2=10
set variable1= 
for /l %%a in (!value1!,1,!value2!) do (
    set percent=%%
    set variable1=!variable1!!percent!b%%a!percent!
)
echo !variable1!
```

You will have to add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` as this will helps to [expand the variable at execution time rather than at parse time](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. However, for my own curiosity, does using ! as a replacement of % tell it to treat that with the setlocal'd `EnableDelayedExpansion`?